# SSRS Matrix is giving me the strange result

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have written a simple query as you can see below.

```
select distinct 
   g.EnglishCountryRegionName,
   g.City,
   f.SalesAmount
From [dbo].[DimGeography] g
inner join FactInternetSales f on f.SalesTerritoryKey = g.SalesTerritoryKey
```

It gives me the following result

[image]

After this I created the matrix where in row grouping I put EnglishCountryRegionName and on column grouping, I put the city as you can see below

[image]

On the column grouping, I use the following expression

```
=iif(left(Fields!City.Value,1)="A",Fields!City.Value,nothing)
```

It gives me the cities that start with the letter "A" but at the end it also gives me the one extra column that is starting with the letter "B" as you can see below.

[image]

Do you know why I am getting the last highlighted column?
Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying top do but your column group will give you two groups, one with anything beginning with "A" and another for everything else. It might be better to explain what you are trying to achieve as I suspect a different approach would be better.

Comment: thanks ALan! Actually I want to display only those designation on columns where it starts with the letter "A". Later I have found that I can achieve it with the help of filtering on column grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same expression both in the grouping and display value.
Change the city value in your tablix with the group expression.

[image]

[image]